# SQL query returns empty set on Comman Line Client

Tags: sql

Currently building a website with an sql database for website users. When I test the site in my browser (through localhost / Abyss web server) all works fine and data shows ok. Problem is when I query the table directly in SQL Command Line client. When I try to select all users, it shows empty set as below even though I know there is data there as it's shown on the site.

```
SELECT * FROM users;
Empty set, 26624 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

Other queries work ok in the command line. eg

```
EXPLAIN users;
```

Shows the table details ok.

Individual queries also work ok in the command line client and return the relevant results proving there is data in the table.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE first_name='John';
```

Returns result ok.

Why could this happen and where would I begin to debug? Why would the site work ok but the command line client only return an empty set. Further, I seem to lose connection to the server after the attempts in the Command Line.

EDIT:

```
SHOW WARNINGS;
```

returns 'Error 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MYSQL server during query'.

Comment: "26624 warnings". What are the warnings? Perhaps they will give more info on the issue?

Comment: @nhouser9 Tried to find these but returns the connection error above..